# javascript automatic image slides

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to make slide images to automatically replace. Here is code i use for manual replacing by clicking on buttoms. Sorry if it is some basics issue, but i don't realy use javascript. I've got it from w3schools, and try to combine the automatic replacing and this, but didn't work.
Thanks for answers.
PS: There are 3 images now and 4 will be.

```
                    var slideIndex = 1;

                    showDivs();

                    function plusDivs(n) {
                      showDivs(slideIndex += n);
                    }

                    function currentDiv(n) {
                      showDivs(slideIndex = n);
                    }

                    function showDivs(n) {
                    var i;
                    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
                    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
                    if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
                    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
                    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                        x[i].style.display = "none";  
                    }
                    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
                        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" w3-white", "");
                    }
                    x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
                    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " w3-white";
                    x[slideIndex-1].style.width = "784px"; 
                    x[slideIndex-1].style.height = "350px";


                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing you need to do is continuously call the function for changing the slides in certain intervals. I am adding the complete code after making changes for the same.

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
var index = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  index++;
  if( self.index == self.slides.length ) {
    index = 0;
  }
  currentSlide( index );

}, 2000);
```

Instead of 2000, you can give any delay you need. Think this solves your problem.